# Can't run Report Layout designer in Nav2013R2

Tags: visual-studio-2010, dynamics-nav

In MS Nav2013R2 I can't open reports layout in Visual Studio
When I click View -Layout in Microsoft Dynamics NAV Development Environment it throws error

`An error occurred when opening the report designer. A supported version of Visual Studio could not be found.`

Tried everything that can be googled: VS2008, VS2008Express, VS2010, instaled Integrated Shell, reinstalled, repaired, rebooted....

Any other options?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need Visual Studio 2012 for that.

Or you can use SQL Server Report Builder, which is installed together with NAV. If you enable the flag "Use Report Builder" in Tools/Options, View/Layout will launch Report Builder instead of VS2012.

http://rsdynamicsnavblog.wordpress.com/2013/09/06/nav2013r2-no-need-for-visual-studio-report-builder-supported/

Comment: Damn it (just looked at [sys. req.](https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdownload.microsoft.com%2Fdownload%2F2%2F4%2F2%2F2425E14F-9346-4F66-9715-DAE3042BE2E1%2FSystemRequirementsNAV2013R2.pdf&ei=gJOVUsS5D4-HyAO9qIGwAg&usg=AFQjCNE2hNjwSo8RXZ6Qg6rMblZR5o69VA&sig2=3dxtLMH2CJG8Vp91L3TBmw&bvm=bv.57155469,d.bGQ)), what the hell have changed from Nav2013 to Nav2013R2 that required VS2012??? It was possible to use VS2010 with Nav2013...

Comment: I believe the main reason is that report format was upgraded once again - from RDLC 2008 to RDLC 2010. There is a [blog post](http://mibuso.com/blogs/clausl/2012/08/08/rdl-vs-rdlc-versions-and-dynamics-nav/) with detailed description and a nice schema.